# <script src="./script.js"></script> (Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input)

Tags: javascript, syntax-error

[**screenshot of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J7RKm.png)

Hello everyone,

I am a complete beginner in coding and have been coding along with a webinar when I received the error: **Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input**. I included a screenshot of the error. This happened I think when I added the inputChange function. The instructor of the webinar did not have any errors, and my code (so far) is identical to his code during the video.

Anybody who can help me understand and solve this issue?

Here is my code:

```js
//Variables, Arrays, and Objects, dotNotation, bracketNotation
//Dom manipulation


let items = [
    {
      name: 'Ironhack T',
      price: 10,
      image: 'https://miro.medium.com/max/5190/1*aVsUjp1zvlRb1799gDjbLA@2x.jpeg'
    },
    {
      name: 'Ironhack Hoodie',
      price: 15,
      image: 'https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/B1i3u9-Q-KS._AC_CLa%7C2140%2C2000%7CB1wqstnnTfS.png%7C0%2C0%2C2140%2C2000%2B0.0%2C0.0%2C2140.0%2C2000.0_UL1500_.png'
    },
    {
      name: 'Ironhack Sticker',
      price: 2,
      image:'https://e7.pngegg.com/pngimages/887/803/png-clipart-ironhack-web-development-job-startup-company-design-blue-user-interface-design-thumbnail.png'
    },
    {
      name: 'Ironhack Mug',
      price: 8,
      image: 'https://d0bb7f9bf11b5ad1a6b2-6175f06f5e3f64e15abbf67415a276ec.ssl.cf1.rackcdn.com/product-images/designlab/11-oz-traditional-ceramic-coffee-mugs-7102-white1582888132.jpg'
    },
  ];

  let list = document.querySelector('ul');


items.forEach((item, i) =>{
    console.log(item.name);
    list.innerHTML += `<li>
    <div>Name: ${item.name}</div>
    <div>Price: $${item.price}</div>
    <img src="${item.image}" />
    <input type='number' placeholder='quantity' onchange='inputChange(${i}, '${item.name}', '${item.price}')' />
    <button>Buy item</button>
    </li>`
});

function inputChange(i, name, price){
console.log('I want to buy the ',i,' item named, ',name,' that costs $',price);
};
```

```css
*{
    transition: all 1s;
}


body{
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: lightseagreen;

}

section{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
}


img {
    width: 50px;
}


#cart{
    background-color:salmon;
}

#cart, #items{
    width: 50vw;
}

h1{
    color:#7c32ff;
}
/*selecting a tag*/

p{
    color:green;
    text-decoration: line-through;
}


/*Ids have hashtags*/
#two {
    background-color:rebeccapurple;
}

/*classes have dots*/
.example {
    border: 5px dashed purple;
    margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
    <!--Now my CSS is linked to my html-->
    <link href="/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" rel="icon" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css" />
</head>

<body>

    <section>

        <div>
            <h2>Items</h2>
            <ul id="items">


            </ul>

        </div>
        <div>
            <h2>Cart <span id="grandTotal">$0</span></h2>
            <ul id="cart">


            </ul>
        </div>

    </section>

    <!-- <div class="example">
        This is a div
    </div>
        
    <div class="example" id="two">
        This is a div 2 
    </div>
        
    <div class="example">
        This is a div 3
    </div>
    <i>This will be italic text</i>
    <b>This will be bold text</b>    
    <h1>This is a certain size</h1>
    <p>This is for paragraphs</p> -->
    <script src="./script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: `script.js` is probably not valid in your local address at `127.0.0.1:5500/script.js`

Comment: Why the extra dot?
This method didn'T solve the problem, unfortunately.

Comment: A single dot indicates the current directory. Two dots indicates up a level.

Comment: You are using only single quotes in the onchange attribute of the input (where you call inputChange). Please try double quotes outside `onchange="..." ` and single quotes inside. Additionally, you don't need single quotes in code like this: `'${item.name}'` (I believe)

Comment: You have a backtick instead of a colon at innerHtml += '<Ii

Comment: The backtick is absolutely fine, because he's using template literals.

Comment: After some investigation I'm sure the problem lies in the template literal string that you add to the innerHTML. inputChange is called already when the page is loaded, but not onchange. I am looking for a solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Edit: Fixing the Single (') and Double (") Quotes in the following code is enough

Notice the *double quotes* wrapping the variables passed to inputChange. And notice the *single quotes* wrapping the complete value passed to the `onchange='...'` attribute

```js
// Inside the forEach loop

  list.innerHTML += `<li>
  <div>Name: ${item.name}</div>
  <div>Price: $${item.price}</div>
  <img src="${item.image}" />
  <input type='number' placeholder='quantity' onchange='inputChange("${i}", "${item.name}", "${item.price}")' />
  <button>Buy item</button>
  </li>`;
```

### Edit: Alternative solution which logs the current value of input additionally

While debugging, I took another solution, which also logs the current value of the input elements (i.e. *how much* the customer wants to buy).

1. Adding only an input element for each item, with an id property for getting it later when the change event fires.
2. Adding event listeners with `.addEventListener("change", inputChange)` - inputChange will receive an `event` object each time the input element is changed.
3. inputChange is the event handler function. It extracts the input element's id, and uses it to find the data (object in `items` array) with the `Array.prototype.find()` (More on this prototype https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)

```js
// script.js

//Variables, Arrays, and Objects, dotNotation, bracketNotation
//Dom manipulation

let items = [
  {
    name: "Ironhack T",
    price: 10,
    image: "https://miro.medium.com/max/5190/1*aVsUjp1zvlRb1799gDjbLA@2x.jpeg",
  },
  {
    name: "Ironhack Hoodie",
    price: 15,
    image:
      "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/B1i3u9-Q-KS._AC_CLa%7C2140%2C2000%7CB1wqstnnTfS.png%7C0%2C0%2C2140%2C2000%2B0.0%2C0.0%2C2140.0%2C2000.0_UL1500_.png",
  },
  {
    name: "Ironhack Sticker",
    price: 2,
    image:
      "https://e7.pngegg.com/pngimages/887/803/png-clipart-ironhack-web-development-job-startup-company-design-blue-user-interface-design-thumbnail.png",
  },
  {
    name: "Ironhack Mug",
    price: 8,
    image:
      "https://d0bb7f9bf11b5ad1a6b2-6175f06f5e3f64e15abbf67415a276ec.ssl.cf1.rackcdn.com/product-images/designlab/11-oz-traditional-ceramic-coffee-mugs-7102-white1582888132.jpg",
  },
];

/* Adds id property to objects inside items array */
items = items.map((item) => ({
  ...item,
  id: item.name.replace(" ", "-").toLowerCase(),
}));

/* inputChange receives event object when the input changes */
function inputChange(event) {
  // for inspection - log the event object
  // console.log(event);
  const { id } = event.target; // the id I gave to the input
  const number = event.target.value; // the current value of the input

  // find the object with the corresponding data in the items array
  const data = items.find((item) => item.id === id);

  console.log(
    `I want to by ${number} of the item named, ${data.name} that costs $${data.price}`
  );
}

let list = document.querySelector("ul");

items.forEach((item, i) => {
  /* prettier-ignore */
  list.innerHTML += `<li>
    <div>Name: ${item.name}</div>
    <div>Price: $${item.price}</div>
    <img src="${item.image}" />
    <input type='number' placeholder='quantity' id=${item.id} />
    <button>Buy item</button>
    </li>`;
});

/* Get all inputs */
const inputs = document.querySelectorAll("input");
inputs.forEach((inputEl) => inputEl.addEventListener("change", inputChange));
```

Additionally, one word concerning file paths in src property of script tag:
Either solution is fine in this case:

`<script src="script.js"></script>`
`<script src="./script.js"></script>`

Answer (score -1):

your code ./script.js are incorrect.
this is some example of HTML File Paths:

```
<srcipt src="script.js">    The "script.js" file is located in the same folder as the current page
<srcipt src="js/script.js"> The "script.js" file is located in the js folder in the current folder
<srcipt src="/js/script.js">    The "script.js" file is located in the js folder at the root of the current web
<srcipt src="../script.js"> The "script.js" file is located in the folder one level up from the current folder
```

Comment: ./script.js is also valid as it is a common notation for a relativ path in the same directory

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Getting_started_with_the_web/Dealing_with_files?retiredLocale=id

Comment: I can't find one dot notation like you're talking about.

Comment: Hi everyone, 
unfortunately, changing the HTML File Path didn't work either. The problem started with the onchange, I just don't know what exactly, because as I said, the instructor of the webinar has identical code and it was working for him.